# Ubuntu выставление прав

Tags: ubuntu

Как правильно выставлять права на папки и файлы в Ubuntu? Есть сервер, к которому подключаюсь удаленно. На нем стоит Nginx. В папку /var/www/html кладу php-файлы, но запустить их не могу удаленно, так как нет прав. Правильно ли будет задавать папке 777 права в целях безопасности?

Comment: Попробуйте лучше задать владельца, от имени которого открываются файлы в nginx. Например, `chown -R www:www /var/www/html`

Answer (score 1):

Нет конечно. 
права на папки - 755, на файлы - 644

[Тут подробнее](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/)

Comment: Хорошо а как быть если я по фтп буду коннектится к серверу и работать с файлами ? Мне же 644 не позволит их модифицировать.

Answer (score 0):

Такое иногда бывает ecли ставил с php-fpm. Если да - то проверь под кем запускается php-fpm в 
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
Должно быть 
user: nginx
group:nginx